# Error with assert for decorator that adds date

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was supposed to write decorator that adds date with given format in an argument to the dict that is being returned by function. Here is my code:

```
import datetime  # do not change this import, use datetime.datetime.now() to get date


def add_date(format):
    def decorator(f):
        def inner(*args):
            dic=dict(f(*args))
            dic['date']=datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format)
            return dic
        return inner
    return decorator

@add_date('%B %Y')
def get_data(a=5):
    return {1: a, 'name': 'Jan'}

assert get_data(2) == {

    1: 2, 'name': 'Jan', 'date': 'April 2020'

}
```

But after running obligatory tests, i don't pass them because of the alert:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/unit_tests.py", line 64, in test_add_date
    self.assertEqual(get_data(a=5), {
TypeError: inner() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'
```

And i have no idea how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `5` as a *keyword* argument (`a=5`), but your `inner` function only takes *positional* arguments (`*args`). Making it accept keyword-arguments (`**kwargs`) like so will fix your issue

```python
def inner(*args, **kwargs):
    dic = dict(f(*args, **kwargs))
    dic['date']=datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format)
    return dic
```

[Check Python documentation for more information on *positional* and *keyword* arguments.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-argument)